# Smooth Scroll Specific Tag Similar Overflow Use OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a div tag "`onlySrollThisID`" can be scroll after the trigger button is pressed. But only that part. For example, here I have the code to scroll at a self-definable speed.

But the code below will run across all content, including headers, sidebars, and footers. While here I try to scroll only on div tag "`onlySrollThisID`" only.

Here's the code code.

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background:#fff;z-index:10">
<button onclick='slowScroll();'>-</button>
<button onclick='fastScroll();'>+</button>
SPEED TEST: <span id='valueScroll'>0</span>
</div>
<br>
HEADER
<hr>

<div id='onlySrollThisID' style="float:left;width:120px">
Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>
</div>


<p>Hello World..</p>
<p>This is Sidebar Right</p>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<hr>
FOOTER


<script type='text/javascript'>

function starScroll(){window.scrollBy(0,1),scrolldelay=setTimeout(starScroll,250)}
function fastScroll(){
starScroll(),valSpeed=document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML,hitSpeed=+valSpeed+17,document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML=hitSpeed;
if(valSpeed<17){window.scrollTo('',0)}
}
function slowScroll(){
clearTimeout(scrolldelay),valSpeed=document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML,hitSpeed=+valSpeed-17;
if(valSpeed>0){document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML=hitSpeed}else{document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML=0}
}

</script>
```

Well, is there a way to scroll on a particular field only? So the position `HEADER, SIDEBAR, FOOTER` will remain there without participating in the scroll.
Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. You just need to update a little code.

Add CSS to "onlySrollThisID"

```
height:90%;overflow:auto; //Adjust to your blog space
```

**Search this code**

```
function starScroll(){
window.scrollBy(0,1),scrolldelay=setTimeout(starScroll,250)
}
```

**Change to**

```
function starScroll(){
$("#onlySrollThisID").scrollTop($("#onlySrollThisID").scrollTop()+1),scrolldelay=setTimeout(starScroll,500);
}
```

**Full Code**

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;background:#fff;z-index:10">
<button onclick='slowScroll();'>-</button>
<button onclick='fastScroll();'>+</button>
SPEED TEST: <span id='valueScroll'>0</span>
</div>
<br>
HEADER
<hr>

<div id='onlySrollThisID' style="float:left;width:120px;height:90%;overflow:auto">
Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>Scroll Me<br>
</div>


<p>Hello World..</p>
<p>This is Sidebar Right</p>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<hr>
FOOTER

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function starScroll(){
$("#onlySrollThisID").scrollTop($("#onlySrollThisID").scrollTop()+1),scrolldelay=setTimeout(starScroll,500);
}
function fastScroll(){
starScroll(),valSpeed=document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML,hitSpeed=+valSpeed+17,document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML=hitSpeed;
if(valSpeed<17){window.scrollTo('',0)}
}
function slowScroll(){
clearTimeout(scrolldelay),valSpeed=document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML,hitSpeed=+valSpeed-17;
if(valSpeed>0){document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML=hitSpeed}else{document.getElementById("valueScroll").innerHTML=0}
}

</script>
```

Example : https://www.chordband.com/guitar/armada_dengerin_abang.htm

Answer (score 0):

The scroll position works similarly for a div.

Try using

```
document.getElementById('onlySrollThisID').scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Replace (0,0) with X,Y positions

Answer (score 0):

How about just fixing the position of the header, footer and sidebar like you did for the first div ?